# Update large collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Does anyone have a suggestion about how to update a field in each document in a large collection?

I use something like this:

```
MyModel.find().exec(function(err,data){
   if(err){
      return console.log(err);
   }
   data.forEach(function(doc){
      doc.Field = doc.Field + 1;
      doc.save(function (err) {
        if(err) {
        console.error('ERROR!');
        }
      });
   });
});
```

But I get `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory`.

Is there a way to process the above update in chunks or something like that?

Comment: How large is your collection? Try increasing memory or swap size of of MongoDB server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`async.eachLimit`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) method of the `async` library to limit the number of concurrent `save` operations (doc link is to `each`, scroll down to see the `eachLimit` variant).

For example, to limit the saves to no more than 5 outstanding at a time:

```js
MyModel.find().exec(function(err, data){
   if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
   }
   async.eachLimit(data, 5, function(doc, callback){
      doc.Field = doc.Field + 1;
      doc.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('ERROR!');
        }
        callback(err);
      });
   });
});
```

However, in this case it would be much more efficient to use a single `update` with the `$inc` operator and the `multi: true` option to increment each doc's `Field` value by 1.

```js
MyModel.update({}, {$inc: {Field: 1}}, {multi: true), function(err) { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

you need more memory: --max_new_space_size and/or --max_old_space_size, like this:

```
node --max-old-space-size=4096 server.js
```

> Currently, by default v8 has a memory limit of 512MB on 32-bit
>   systems, and 1.4GB on 64-bit systems. The limit can be raised by
>   setting --max_old_space_size to a maximum of ~1024 (~1 GB) (32-bit)
>   and ~4096 (~4GB) (64-bit), but it is recommended that you split your
>   single process into several workers if you are hitting memory limits

Comment: Good find. I wasn't aware of. +1